# MySQL:Select LIKE doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code that searches on a DB if a name exists:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

$get_search_results_q= "SELECT * FROM `users`.`info` WHERE `info`.`fullname` LIKE '%$name%' ";
$get_search_results_run=mysql_query($get_search_results_q); 
if($get_search_results_run==0){
    echo "No results were found";
}else{
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_search_results_run,MYSQL_NUM)){
        $com_array[] = $rows[3];
    }
    echo json_encode($com_array);
}

?>
```

It works fine when i type a name that exists in DB.
But when i type something that doesn't exist nothing is returned.
This is the jQuery AJAX code that displays the data:

```
.done(function(data) {
                var result = eval(data);
                if(!result){
                    $(".results").empty();
                    $(".results").append('<div class="horizontal result_element">'+result+'</div>');
                    $("#search_result_box").show();
                }else{
                    $(".results").empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        $(".results").append('<div class="horizontal result_element"><div class="result_photo"></div><div class="result_data">'+result[i]+'</div></div>');
                    }
                    $("#search_result_box").show();
                }
                });
```

I tried many things,like to display the data on jQuery and the mysql_query result but nothing happens.

Comment: If there is no match why would you expect anything to be returned?

Comment: mysql_query is intended to return false when no results returned on a SELECT statement.

Comment: No that is incorrect http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
I get none of them...

Comment: Presently it does not `echo "No results were found";` ?

Comment: what about `echo json_encode(array('error' => 'No results were found"'));`?

Comment: 1) Enable proper error_reporting, if that is not in place already. 2) Make a debug output of `$get_search_results_run` using `var_dump`.

Comment: @tttony it doesn't work because the it doesn't enter the if statement.I have used the var_dumb and nothing happens too.

Comment: This is not an answer, just some suggestions: Don't use mysql_* it's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.
And NEVER put input variable into a query string. It's a very bad and dangerous. (Read a bit about Sql injection!)

Comment: Found the problem! The general problem was the one that kefy mentioned.It wanted object jason format but this array: $error['message_message'] = "No results were found"; needed to be modified to: $error[0] = "No results were found"; And then in jQuery change this: result.error to this: result[0]==="No results were found" And it worked.

Comment: Note that the mysql extension [is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info about PDO and mysqli but i know that they exist and what's their job long time now.This is actualy a code that it was developed some time ago and i wanted to check what was the problem.When i finish with the project i will move on mysqli().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($get_search_results_run);
if(!$total_rows){
   echo "No results were found";
}else{
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_search_results_run,MYSQL_NUM)){
      $com_array[] = $rows[3];
   }
   echo json_encode($com_array);
}
```

**EDIT**

I think because you send error type not in object json format, try this :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$get_search_results_q= "SELECT * FROM `users`.`info` WHERE `info`.`fullname` LIKE '%$name%' ";
// I missing this before
$get_search_results_run = mysql_query($get_search_results_q);
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($get_search_results_run);
if(!$total_rows){
   $error['message_message'] = "No results were found";
   echo json_encode($error);
}else{
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_search_results_run,MYSQL_NUM)){
      $com_array[] = $rows[3];
   }
   echo json_encode($com_array);
}

.done(function(data) {
                var result = eval(data);
                if(result.error){
                    $(".results").empty();
                    $(".results").append('<div class="horizontal result_element">'+result.error+'</div>');
                    $("#search_result_box").show();
                }else{
                    $(".results").empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        $(".results").append('<div class="horizontal result_element"><div class="result_photo"></div><div class="result_data">'+result[i]+'</div></div>');
                    }
                    $("#search_result_box").show();
                }
                });
```

Comment: Found the problem!
The general problem was the one that kefy mentioned.It wanted object jason format but this array:
$error['message_message'] = "No results were found"; needed to be modified to:
$error[0] = "No results were found";
And then in jQuery change this:
result.error
to this:
result[0]==="No results were found"
And it worked.

Comment: OK Congratulations @garrytowel